# Change sections font with amsart

Tags: fonts

I’m using the `amsart` class and the package `txfonts` in order to using the Times font. I want the titles of the sections, subsections, … with Latin Modern Sans font.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, reqno, 10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% title font
\newcommand*\sectfont{\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont} 

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

It doesn’t work and I can’t understand why. I also have tried with `sectsty` package and LaTeX has given me an error.
What is the correct way to change only the type of font (not bold, italic, dimension, …) of the titles with `amsart` class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You wrote, "I also have tried with `sectsty` package and LaTeX has give[n] me an error. " What exactly did you try, and what's the error message you got? Please be specific.

Comment: The code you provided does not result in an error if I compile it (after having added some code as the body of the document where I placed the `\sectfont` macro).

Comment: The problem is that the code doesn’t return the titles of the sections with the changed font. @JasperHabicht

Comment: This is the error: Package sectsty Error: The sectsty package doesn't work with(sectsty) this document class. scrartcl, scrbook, and scrreprt.} @Mico

Comment: @alessandro The code that you posted above does not return anything (except to the log), of course, and compiles *without* any error. So, as long as you don't provide a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927) that produces the said error, we are virtually unable to help you, even though you told us more about the error you get. We need to know how you set up your section titles etc. and how they are styled.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have uplaoded the code. I want "Section 1", title of the section, with Latin Modern Sans font, while it is in Times New Roman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font choice is hardwired the sectional command definitions. And `sectsty` is not compatible with `amsart`.

You can patch the commands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, reqno, 10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}

\patchcmd{\part}{\normalfont}{\alessandrofont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\specialsection}{\normalfont}{\alessandrofont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\scshape}{\alessandrofont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\alessandrofont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{\alessandrofont}{}{}
\newcommand{\alessandrofont}{\normalfont\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\section{This is lmss}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid `txfonts`: the font metrics it uses are bad. Using NewTX is much better.

Comment: Thank you @egreg